# Is it possible to clone a AVPlayerLayer?

Tags: ios, avplayerlayer

I need to play one video in three different layers using the same AVPlayerLayer object.
Is it possible to clone a AVPlayerLayer so that I can use cloned layers where I need?

Comment: Did you ever succeed at this? I'm finding myself in the same spot.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with

```
NSMutableArray *videoLayersArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[videoLayersArray addObject:layer1];
[videoLayersArray addObject:layer2];
[videoLayersArray addObject:layer3];
// add these three layers on parentLayer

videoComposition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayers:videoLayersArray inLayer:parentLayer];
```

This will render your video which in composition in layer1. layer2 and layer3.
It worked for me.